# Why does removeClass() work but hasClass() doesn't?

Tags: jquery, css, class

I am using some CSS classes and jQuery to make a custom selectbox. But I keep having problems with the removeClass() function.
I know there are alternatives to this problem. But could somebody explain me WHY it is not working?

```js
$(".filterselect").on("click",function(){
  $(this).find("ul").addClass("open");
});

$(".filterselect ul li").on("click",function(){
  $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass("active"); // THIS WORKS
  $(this).addClass("active"); // THIS WORKS
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("open"))
  {
    console.log("test"); // THIS WORKS
  }
  $(this).parent().removeClass("open"); // THIS DOESN'T WORK :(
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="filter driedelig mw1">
  <div class="filteritem">
    <div class="filterselect">
      <ul>
        <li class="active">Categorie 1</li>
        <li>Caetgorie 2</li>
        <li>Categorie 3</li>
      </ul>
      <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML. We need a [mcve]

Comment: For addClass you using find(“ul”) can you do the same for removeClass? You probably not selecting the right parent/element..

Comment: I added the html @j08691

Answer (score 2):

The event is bubbling up, causing the `.filterselect` click handler to fire again. So it *is* removing the class, just adding it back up.

If you stop the propagation of the event it won't happen but won't get the class in the first place, either since the `.filterselect` won't get the event at all.

You can change your function to this, and it'll work as expected:

```js
$(".filterselect").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find("ul").addClass("open");
});

$(".filterselect ul li").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("open")) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("open");
    console.log("Remove class");
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="filter driedelig mw1">
  <div class="filteritem">
    <div class="filterselect">
      <ul>
        <li>Categorie 1</li>
        <li>Categorie 2</li>
        <li>Categorie 3</li>
      </ul>
      <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

As you say, there are other ways of dealing with this. One of which is removing the `.filterselect` click handler and managing the `ul` state from the child. This will allow the event to still bubble up if there is any behaviour in the page that relies on it:

```
$("ul li").on("click",function(){
  $parent = $(this).parent(); // Cache the selector
  $parent.find("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  if ($parent.hasClass("open")) {
    $parent.removeClass("open");
  } else {
    $parent.addClass("open");
  }
});
```

Comment: It works like a charm! thanks for the explanation.. ;)